# PHP: Converting scandic characters to hex unicode

Tags: php, unicode, json, non-unicode

I'm working on a **Joomla** site with Fabrik and problem is that Fabrik serializes some data using json_encode() but does not take into account the possibility of åäö and such. Now when a database search is made, it tries to find stuff with åäö, but doesn't find anything, because

> everything is \u00e4 and \u00f6

and so forth.

I'm not much for digging into Fabrik's code and inserting one flag somewhere and worry about accidentally overwriting it when I update Fabrik. So I figured, since I'm disappointed in Fabrik anyway, I could just write around it completely in a custom template. Easy.

The problem is that I can't find a way or a function like htmlentities() that I can just feed the stuff to to make it match. I could just character replace them, but that's not a good solution.

Paraphrase: **I wanna make word Mörkö into -> M\u00f6rk\u00f6. How?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there's another way but that works as excepted :

```
$encoded = substr(json_encode('Mörkö'), 1, -1);
```

---

`json_encode('Mörkö')` => "M\u00f6rk\u00f6"

`substr()` => M\u00f6rk\u00f6

Comment: Anyway, given that it's a "json-encoding", I don't think there a better way to do this, after all !